# How to link to another page content in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in building a website and I don't have a basic programming knowledge.

I try to build a html website which can display many gif animations.How to link the navigation List lets say nav_work to display only the work content ?

```html
<div id="navigation_bar">
<ul id="navList">
<li><a id="nav_home" class="menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>

<li><a id="nav_work" class="menu" href="work.html">Work</a></li>

<li><a id="nav_about" class="menu" href="about.html">About</a></li>

<li><a id="nav_contact" class="menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TP8h.jpg)

Comment: it's not clear what you asking and whats your problem. explain more as you can

Comment: @Sally_2891 what do you mean by link? do you mean iframe tag ?

Comment: is your question like how to create a new page for work? if so create work.html file and include all the gifs in it

Comment: you need to create a new file called work.html - the link will then navigate to that file.

Comment: Sorry , I will post the image for you to see.

Comment: @Shiljo yes, I hope can create a new page for work when I click the nav_work,

Comment: If you want to create the page *when* the link is clicked, then you'll need to do some server side programming. Going from "I don't have a basic programming knowledge" to that is far too broad a topic for Stackoverflow. If you just want to link to an existing page … then you just write the HTML for that page in the same way you write it for any other page.

Comment: If I want to change the content animation with pagination 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can simple use the  **#** for the navigation.

**Example 1**

```
<a href="#work">Work</a>
```

will target the the div with an id "work"
`<div id="work">ABC</div>`
**Example 2**

```
<a href="work.html">Work</a>
```

will target the work.html page

**Example 3**

```
<a href="work.html#work">Work</a>
```

will target the div with an id **work** from the work.html page